# Sum of n-1 columns of a double matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 1*3000 double matrix. I am doing some calculation and I need to calculate sum of n-1 columns in each step.

For example, if I have this matrix:

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

The summation I'm looking for should be like this:

```
B = [0 1 1+2 1+2+3 1+2+3+4 1+2+3+4+5] = [0 1 3 6 10 15]
```

Meaning, in each step, we calculate the sum of n-1 columns of the matrix while n starts from 1 to the number of columns of the matrix.

Since the number of columns is 3000, I cannot use 'for' loop.

Could you please tell me what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using the function `cumsum`:

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
C = cumsum(A);
out = [0 C(1:end-1)]
```

now `out` is: `[0  1  3  6  10  15]`

Answer (score 0):

If you only need one value of B, you can use `sum(A(1:n))` to calculate that value. If you need to calculate all 3000 values of B, I think you will do good with a for loop. 3000 iterations isn't much if you use this:

```
A = 1:3000;
B = zeros(1, 3000);
B(1) = A(1);
for i = 2:3000
    B(i) = B(i-1) + A(i);
end
```